# Uploading a file with cfhttp appends a newline (even on binary files)

Tags: forms, coldfusion, file-upload

**Update**: I've found a workaround. If I submit a dummy form field along with the file, it works. Is this a ColdFusion bug, or is there something in the HTTP spec that says forms must contain at least one non-file form field?

**Update 2**: I'm convinced this is a ColdFusion cfhttp bug. This is based on Leigh's answer and the fact that I used the code below to submit a form with *only* the file element using javascript, and it works fine:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<cfoutput>#CGI.PATH_INFO#</cfoutput>" method="POST" name="theForm">
  <input name="theFile" type="file" /><br/>
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.theForm.submit()">submit</a>
```

---

I'm running into a problem uploading files from a ColdFusion server to another webserver. It seems that `cfhttpparam type="file"` is indiscriminately appending a newline (carriage return and line feed) to the end of the file. This is breaking binary files. This *does not* happen when I manually upload the file via form field. I have tried with and without mimetype parameter, and I've tried lying about mimetype with various binary formats (exe, zip, jpg), but nothing has worked. Is there some parameter I'm missing, or is this a bug in ColdFusion?  (I'm running on CF 8.0.1.195765 on WinXP.)

Below is test code I'm using, it just uploads the file to the same directory. The manual upload works, but the server-based upload ends up appending a CRLF to the file.

```
<cfset MyDir = "C:\test" />
<cfset MyFile = "test.zip" />

<cfif IsDefined("Form.TheFile")>
  <cffile action="upload" fileField="theFile" destination="#MyDir#" nameConflict="MakeUnique" />
<cfelse>
  <cfhttp url="http://#CGI.SERVER_NAME##CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="POST" throwOnError="Yes">
    <cfhttpparam type="file" name="theFile" file="#MyDir#\#MyFile#" />
  </cfhttp>
</cfif>

<html><body>
<h2>Manual upload</h2>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<cfoutput>#CGI.PATH_INFO#</cfoutput>" method="POST">
  <input name="theFile" type="file" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I remember that problem. I am not sure about the specs, but my _guess_ at the time was cfhttp issue. Hopefully someone else has a more definitive answer..

Comment: My guess is that this is a browser or http problem, not a problem with CF.  There was a similar problem back in IE on Mac Classic (yes, it's been a while) that would append newlines to any multipart/mime form.  I would guess this is a similar, less intrusive problem.  the upload action is just a file copy from the file handle provided by the web server (IIS, Apache, etc.)

Comment: Your suggestion would make more sense. But I am still leaning towards cfhttp issue. I just tried it with the developer version (built in web server) and got the same corrupted file results with IE and FF.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure it is a cfhttp bug too. Thinking about it, cfhttp is what constructs the request content. So cfhttp is responsible for adding new lines in between the boundary markers. In this case, one too many..

Comment: This basic problem happens in ACF to the last form field in the CFHTTP call regardless of it being a form field. The final text field will have a new line character appended. It does not happen if there is not a file field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or is there something in the HTTP spec
>   that says forms must contain at least
>   one non-file form field?

I do not know for certain. But according to [these definitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) it seems like a POST containing only a file input should be valid. So I suspect the problem may be CFHTTP in ACF.

According to [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) the raw content from the cfhttp call in ACF contains an extra new line just before the end boundary (0D 0A in hex view). But under Railo it does not. So I think ACF's cfhttp might be the culprit.

**Sample Code:**

```
<cfhttp url="http://127.0.0.1:8888/cfusion/receive.cfm" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam name="myFile" type="file" file="c:/test/testFile.zip" mimetype="application/octet-stream" />
</cfhttp>
```

**Results Railo 3.1.2**

```
POST /railo/receive.cfm HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Railo (CFML Engine)
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Content-Length: 382
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=m_l7PD5xIydR_hQpo8fDxL0Hb7vu_F8DSzwn

--m_l7PD5xIydR_hQpo8fDxL0Hb7vu_F8DSzwn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="testFile.zip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PK
&�1=�cN'testFile.txtTestingPK
&�1=�cN' testFile.txtPK:1
--m_l7PD5xIydR_hQpo8fDxL0Hb7vu_F8DSzwn--
```

**Results ACF (versions 8 and 9)**

```
POST /cfusion/receive.cfm HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
... other headers removed for brevity ....
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------7d0d117230764
Content-length: 350

-------------------------------7d0d117230764
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="JobFile"; filename="c:\test\testFile.zip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

PK
&�1=�cN'testFile.txtTestingPK
&�1=�cN' testFile.txtPK:1

-------------------------------7d0d117230764--
```

Comment: @Kip - Okay, good. I was going to ask about that. I remember seeing this issue about 2 years ago, and got as far as figuring out there was an extra 2 bytes being added to all files. But never got around to figuring out why. So thanks for prompting me to solve the nagging mystery ;)

Comment: @Kip - BTW: What is the bug number? I did not see anything in the public bug db.

Comment: @Leigh where is the public bug db? I found this page: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform and I just got a message saying something to the effect of "thanks for submitting your bug. we appreciate your feedback but we cannot reply to every request that is sent in."

Comment: @Kip - The public bug database is here http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html . You might want to list it under CF9.0, because it is still an issue in that version.

Comment: @Leigh: thanks, I've reported it there too: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=84276

Comment: FYI, I just ran into another similar bug. If you use the workaround (include a dummy form field), and the file is empty (0 bytes), you get a 500 internal server exception. But without the dummy field, it works (but still appends an extra newline).

Comment: Seems to work for me with CF9. Maybe that one is CF8 specific?

Comment: Can you please post a more specific example of your work around? This has me stumped!

Comment: I do not remember the specifics. The old bug report probably had an example, but unfortunately Adobe broke the old bug links when upgrading the bug database. However, I think the OP just appended a fake form field ie `<cfhttpparam name="dummyField" type="formField" value="">`.  BTW, I did not down vote it, but S.O. uses a Q&A (question and answer) format, so it works differently than your typical forum. This section is only for posting "answers". If none of the existing answers helped, you are better off opening a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Railo 3.1.2 and ColdFusion 9 handle this a bit differently, but your code looks a bit incorrect for me.

Your `CGI.PATH_INFO` is not applicable here.

While browser is smart enough to use path without hostname, CFHTTP feels better with full hostname + script path + script name. Note: `cgi.SCRIPT_NAME` worked in CF9, Railo required `cgi.SERVER_NAME` to be prepended, though I feel this more correct in general.

That's why a bit modified version of the code works fine for me. Zip file is uploaded and posted without being corrupted.

Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<cfoutput>#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#</cfoutput>" method="POST">
  <input name="theFile" type="file" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

CFHTTP:

```
  <cfhttp url="#cgi.SERVER_NAME##cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="POST" throwOnError="Yes">
    <cfhttpparam type="file" name="theFile" file="#MyDir#/#MyFile#" />
  </cfhttp>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will have try it with Railo. But when I tested the original code, I used hard coded paths and full url's and still got the same corrupted results.  According to Fiddler, the raw content from ACF cfhttp does contain an extra 2 bytes (new line). As soon as you add a dummy field _after_ the file, the extra bytes in the raw content go away.

Comment: sorry, this was an error on my part during anonymizing. in my local script i just have the URL hard-coded.

Comment: still fails with `#cgi.SERVER_NAME##cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#`. I've also tried using javascript to submit a form containing only the file element and it works just fine (see my edit). So i'm pretty sure it's a bug in cfhttp.

Answer (score 1):

I get the extra line feed and carriage return on file appends too. The problem for me is/was the combination of cfhttp and the cfloop. Once I broke the file creation into 3 parts: Create, cfloop endrow-1, then appending last record.

Seems like a kludgy way to do it, but no extra line feed.